# Is it possible to put a Content Editor Web Part in a sharepoint app page

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

Is it possible to put a Content Editor Web Part in a sharepoint app page along with the ability to edit the web parts contents from the browser? In other words have it behave as it would on a web part page.

I can get the web part to show but I have no clue if it can be setup for in browser editing on the application page ... I can't get it to show the edit button.

Jay

Answer (score 1):

You can put a Content Editor WebPart on an application page because it's just a special kind of web control, but there is no web part manager on the page and even if you added one it would not have a record in a content database for the page. So it would not know where to store the information.